# How to improve interp with akima?

Tags: r

I have three variables(the third is relative frequency of two physical values).

```
x <- rnorm(1398)
y <- rnorm(1398)
a1 <- rnorm(1398)
data <- data.frame(x, y, a1)
```

First step is with akima,latter filled.contour.

```
fld <- with(data, interp(x,y,a1))
filled.contour(x=fld$x,y=fld$y,z=fld$z,
  color.palette=colorRampPalette(c("white", "blue")))
```

The problem that arises here is that range on the colorbar scale are 0.0008-0.0018.
But when I check

```
> max(a1)
[1] 0.004291845
> min(a1)
[1] 0.0007153076
```

How to calculate fld to fully represent data?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I get `range(a1)` as `-2.931849  3.077989` as expected. Try again from a clean R session.

Comment: more specifically, `set.seed(101); range(rnorm(1398))` gives `-3.177210  3.178489` and should *always* give something approximately (-3,3).  Otherwise `a1` is being generated in a different way or `rnorm` is broken (!)

Comment: Yes,it has been generated the other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for `interp`, regarding the `xo` argument:

> vector of x-coordinates of output grid. **The default is 40 points
>   evenly spaced over the range of x.**

So the x in `fld` may not include the x-value corresponding to your maximum or minimum a1 values.

By increasing the number of points for `xo` and `yo`, the max `z` value interpolated will get closer to the actual max. For example,

```
set.seed(100)
x <- rnorm(1398)
y <- rnorm(1398)
a1 <- rnorm(1398)
data <- data.frame(x, y, a1)
fld <- with(data, interp(x,y,a1))
fld2 <- with(data, interp(x,y,a1, xo=seq(min(x), max(x), length=1000), yo=seq(min(y), max(y), length=1000)))

max(a1, na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 2.949
max(fld$z, na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 2.481
max(fld2$z, na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 2.902
```

Furthermore, if you want the interpolated z to include your max and min a1, add corresponding x and y values to xo and yo. For example, this is how you would get it to include the max value of a1.

```
max.a1.x <- x[which.max(a1)]
max.a1.y <- y[which.max(a1)]
# these have to be sorted, since filled.contour will expect them to be.
xo <- sort(c(seq(min(x), max(x), length=40), max.a1.x))
yo <- sort(c(seq(min(y), max(y), length=40), max.a1.y))


fld3 <- with(data, interp(x,y,a1, xo=xo, yo=yo))
filled.contour(x=fld3$x,y=fld3$y,z=fld3$z,
  color.palette=colorRampPalette(c("white", "blue")))

max(fld3$z, na.rm=TRUE)
# [1] 2.949
```

Comment: It would never be this bad though. Have you tried it?

Comment: `a1 <- rnorm(1398)` results in a `min(a1)` of 0.0007 and a `max(a1)` of 0.0042 in the original example. Not Ever Going To Happen. Its going to be a few sigma. The OP has done something wrong that we can't see. The fact that he says its a "relative frequency" makes me think its not what we're getting.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. Obviously, his `a1` is not being generated with `rnorm` as in his sample data. But none-the-less, he's complaining about the colorbar scale not matching his original range and this is an explanation of why that might be.

Comment: I've removed my downvote, you probably are answering his *intended* question, if not the one defined by his data!

Comment: Yes,my a1 has not been generated with rnorm(it is actually original data).

Answer (score -1):

I have added original data at pastbin.

http://pastebin.com/ydL0fhfD

I think it could be read as data.frame.

Regarding the problem,Matthew suggested more points,yes I have tried this but still that just slightly improves results.

```
> max(fld2$z, na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 0.002222537
> max(a1, na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 0.004291845
```

Comment: This information is better suited as an addendum to your post, not as an answer. I've updated my answer to show you how to force interp to output your max/min a1 values.